# How to get intermediate Integer solutions when solving a MIP in Julia (JuMP)?

Tags: integer, julia, cplex, julia-jump, mixed-integer-programming

I am solving a MIP model using CPLEX in Julia. I know CPLEX has a so-called Solution Pool where all the intermediate integer solutions during the solving process are stored. Is there a way of accessing those solutions using Julia (JuMP)?

Comment: It is possible to [access the low-level model](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/0.18/refmodel.html#accessing-the-low-level-model) to use some solver functionality that is not otherwise exposed through JuMP. However, looking at the [CPLEX interface](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/CPLEX.jl) it does not look like the solution pool is available. You'll probably have to contact the authors of the JuliaOpt package to get specifics.

Comment: If the solution pool is not available through the CPLEX interface, an _ugly_ workaround would be to use the [lazy constraints callback](http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/callbacks.html). It is called every time a new integer solution is found.